# Swipe Gestures For Android Flex+AIR App

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, swipe-gesture

Is there a way to expand this code to swipe to more than just the 3 views in this code?

Main.MXML

```
 private function handleSwipe(event:TransformGestureEvent):void
    {
    var slideViewTransition:SlideViewTransition = new SlideViewTransition();    
    // Swipe was to the right
    if (event.offsetX == 1 ) {
    slideViewTransition.direction = ViewTransitionDirection.RIGHT;
    navigator.pushView( PreviousView, null, null, slideViewTransition );
    }
    // Swipe was to the left
    else if (event.offsetX == -1 ) {
    slideViewTransition.direction = ViewTransitionDirection.LEFT;
    navigator.pushView( NextView, null, null, slideViewTransition );
    }
    }
```

NextView.MXML

```
import spark.transitions.SlideViewTransition;
import spark.transitions.ViewTransitionDirection;   
private function handleSwipe(event:TransformGestureEvent):void
{
var slideViewTransition:SlideViewTransition = new SlideViewTransition();
if (event.offsetX == 1 ) {
slideViewTransition.direction = ViewTransitionDirection.LEFT;
navigator.pushView( ThreeView, null, null, slideViewTransition );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More correct way is to move this logic (swipe gesture handling) out of the views to the main class. Than all you'll need to add to the existing handling is getting new view class.

Comment: Thanks ill give that a try and see how it goes